# Virtual Default Destructors in C++

Tags: c++, virtual-destructor

I've got a large set of inherited classes (criteria) which inherit from a base class (criterion). Here's `criterion`'s code

```
class criterion
{
public:
    virtual unsigned __int32 getPriorityClass() const = 0;
    virtual BOOL include(fileData &file) const = 0;
    virtual void reorderTree() = 0;
    virtual unsigned int directoryCheck(const std::wstring& directory) const = 0;
    virtual std::wstring debugTree() const = 0;
};
```

Some examples of derived classes from this one:

```
class fastFilter : public criterion
{
public:
    void reorderTree() {};
    unsigned int  directoryCheck(const std::wstring& /*directory*/) const { return DIRECTORY_DONTCARE; };
    unsigned __int32 getPriorityClass() const { return PRIORITY_FAST_FILTER; };
};

class isArchive : public fastFilter
{
public:
    BOOL include(fileData &file) const
    {
        return file.getArchive();
    }
    std::wstring debugTree() const
    {
        return std::wstring(L"+ ISARCHIVE\n");
    };
};
```

Since I don't have a destructor here at all, but yet this is supposed to be a base class, do I need to insert an empty virtual destructor, I.e. like this?:

```
virtual void ~criterion() = 0;
```

If that virtual destructor declaration is needed, do all intermediate classes need one as well? I.e. would fastFilter above need a virtual destructor as well?

Comment: The above is not an empty destructor.  It's a destructor that is also a pure virtual function.  This has nothing to do with being empty, and in fact the destructor is special in that it must always have a definition even when it's pure virtual.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes - the base class needs a virtual destructor, even if it's empty.  If that is not done, then when something `delete`'s a derived object through a base pointer/reference, the derived object's member objects will not get a chance to destroy themselves properly.

Derived classes do not need to declare or define their own destructor unless they need something other than default destructor behavior.

Comment: why not mark it as default? Instead of "= 0" put down "= default"

Answer (score 33):

The recommendation is to insert:

```
virtual ~criterion() {}
```

Starting from C++11, you can use `= default;` instead of an empty body `{}`.

This is to avoid problems with deleting from a base class' pointer. Otherwise you will leak memory as derived classes' destructors will not be called.

```
criterion *c = new fastFilter();
delete c; // leaks
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use an empty destructor over a pure virtual one?

Comment: Isn't `virtual ~criterion() noexcept {}` prettier?

Comment: @user1095108, isn't `virtual ~criterion() = default` prettier?

Comment: @user35443: the "=default" didn't exist in 2009. It is something added in C++11. Yes, nowadays I think that would be the preferred option.

Comment: @Pacheco Ah, it appears so that three years ago I didn't notice the answer had been written in '09. Geez, time flies...

Answer (score 13):

You don't need to make the destructor abstract, just give it a empty implementation:

```
virtual ~criterion() { }
```

This way you are not forced to implement it in every child class, but still each of them will have a (inherited) virtual destructor.

Answer (score 7):

One small change from what others have already answered:

Instead of

```
virtual void ~criterion() = 0;
```

the required version is:

```
    virtual ~criterion() {}  //Note: Removed void as destructors not allowed 
                             //  a return type
```

To know more about virtual destructor have a look at this link from FAQ [When should my destructor be virtual?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.7)