# Forwarding a shared_ptr without class declaration

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

*NOTE*: I've found the source of the error is not actually related to the shared_ptr, just cleverly disguised as such in the error message.  Thus the below is basically nonsense (not the answers, they're fine)

--

I'm having some trouble using a `shared_ptr` (boost's at the moment) where I need to simply forward a pointer to another function. Using native pointers the intervening function would not need to have access to the definition of the class, but using smart_ptr's it appears it does. Is there any way to avoid this?

For example, given a target function:

```
void func( shared_ptr<SomeClass> const & obj )
```

The `const &` takes care of part of the problem, but say we have a getter class which obtains the object for some other class, like:

```
shared_ptr<SomeClass> someClassInstance();
```

And here is where I'd like to simply assemble arguments and forward to the target function:

```
func( someClassInstance() );
```

With a plain pointer this point in the code could simply use a forward declaration of `SomeClass`, but with a `smart_ptr` it needs to have the full definition (presumably as the smart_ptr might need to delete the class).

Now, if `someClassInstance` were to return a `const &` this problem would actually go away as the intervening code would not be copying any objects. However, the getter function *must* return the copy for thread-safety reasons.

Is there anyway I can achieve this type of smart pointer parameter forwarding without needing the class definition? That is, can I use smart pointers in the same fashion as I would a traditional pointer in this circumstance.

--

*UPDATE*: Writing a small test the answers are correct that a forward declaration is enough. Yet GCC is still complaining in one situation. I'm going to have to figure out exactly what is causing it to fail (in this particular situation).

*Do I close this question for now, or what?*

Comment: Why do you want to pass a `shared_ptr` by reference? Could a reference to the concrete type suffice? Also you have some sort of misconception, `shared_ptr` does not require the full definition of the type to be passed around, it works with incomplete types.

Comment: you can't make `func` a template?

Comment: I'm just trying to pass by reference to avoid the problem (it helps in some cases). I guess I need to isolate the situation better in which it doesn't work.

Comment: What makes you think you need the full definition? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Could you post a minimal testcase for which gcc would complain?

Comment: @phresnel, the unexpected source of the error is actually a typeid: see my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523878/obtaining-the-type-name-of-a-template-type-without-class-definition

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need at least a forward declaration for `T` for every mention of `shared_ptr<T>`.

Only if you use unary `shared_ptr::operator*` and `shared_ptr::operator->`, the full thing is needed. Under the hood, `shared_ptr` uses a mix of compiletime- and runtime-polymorphism, making this possible. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3899790/76722) to learn about the "magic".

Example:

```
// frob.h
#ifndef FROB_H
#define FROB_H

#include <shared_ptr>

class Foo;
void grind (std::shared_ptr<Foo>);

#endif
```

Note that the canonical way to pass `shared_ptr` is by value (i.e. remove the `const&`).

Comment: Forward declaration is not enough. Since assigning by value might delete the underlying object you need to have the full definition. (This is the reason why I use const & to avoid this problem, but it doesn't always work).

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y That’s not true. Assignment uses a custom deleter that is fixed by the constructor. Forward declaration is enough for the usage of `shared_ptr`; you only need the definition when calling its constructor.

Comment: under the hood `shared_ptr` uses a mix of runtime- and compiletime-polymorphism, which is why you actually don't need a full definition of the held type, provided you don't use `shared_ptr::operator->` and unary `shared_ptr::operator*`. Try it :)

Comment: @edA-qa mort-ora-y: What do you mean by *assigning by value*? How does it affect? (Note that `shared_ptr` does not require a complete type for deletion, only for creation.

Comment: @Konrad, that's what a colleague also said, now I'm trying to get GCC to agree with that statement.

Comment: I'll just accept this answer, my question is bogus -- this answer is valid.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, shared pointers are specifically designed to work with incomplete types (a killer feature IMO). They require only a forward declaration of a class, not the class definition. From the [Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm):

> Note that scoped_ptr requires that T be a complete type at destruction time, but shared_ptr does not.

You can find a discussion of how this works [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/331786-dealing-with-incomplete-types-boostshared_ptr-style/).

Since shared pointers should work with incomplete types, can you give us a specific (minimal) example in which this doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that **explicit** forward declaration is not always required:

```
using PtrX = std::shared_ptr<class X>;
using PtrW = std::weak_ptr<X>;
```

Here `class X` inside template argument does the magic.