# How do smart pointers choose between delete and delete[]?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, delete-operator

Consider:

```
delete new std :: string [2];
delete [] new std :: string;
```

Everyone knows the first is an error. If the second wasn't an error, we wouldn't need two distinct operators.

Now consider:

```
std :: unique_ptr <int> x (new int [2]);
std :: unique_ptr <int> y (new int);
```

Does `x` know to use `delete[]` as opposed to  `delete`?

---

Background: this question floated through my head when I thought array type qualification of pointers would be a handy language feature.

```
int *[] foo = new int [2]; // OK
int *   bar = new int;     // OK
delete [] foo;             // OK
delete bar;                // OK
foo = new int;             // Compile error
bar = new int[2];          // Compile error
delete foo;                // Compile error
delete [] bar;             // Compile error
```

Comment: Instead of modifying the array type qualifier (which already exists) to work the way you show, it would be better to just eliminate all the implicit type conversions that cause all the problems with arrays. For example `new int[2]` ought to return a value of type `int (*)[2]`. Anyway, it's too late to fix all the problems with native arrays, but you can use `std::array` and avoid ever having to deal with them. `std::array` works like native arrays should work and you never have to use `new[]` or `delete[]`.

Comment: @bames53, There is a limitation with `std::array`. You can do `new int[n]`, but you can't do `std::array<int,n>`. (Unless `n` is known at compile time). But still, I avoid native arrays!#

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Yeah, use `std::vector` if you need dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Unfortunately, they don't know what delete to use therefore they use `delete`. That's why for each smart pointer we have a smart array counterpart.

```
std::shared_ptr uses delete
std::shared_array uses delete[]
```

So, your line

```
std :: unique_ptr <int> x (new int [2]);
```

actually causes undefined behavior.

Incidentally, if you write

```
std :: unique_ptr<int[]> p(new int[2]);
                     ^^
```

then `delete[]` will be used since you've explicitly requested that. However, the following line will still be UB.

```
std :: unique_ptr<int[]> p(new int);
```

The reason that they can't choose between `delete` and `delete[]` is that `new int` and `new int[2]` are exactly of the same type - `int*`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899790/shared-ptr-magic)'s a related question of using correct deleters in case of `smart_ptr<void>` and `smart_ptr<Base>` when `Base` has no virtual destructor.

Comment: @tenfour: Because the types are exactly the same!

Comment: Because they can't detect `std::shared_ptr<int> make (int *i) {return i;}`

Comment: @tenfour: `(new int)` and `(new int[2])` both have type `int*`, there's no way to distinguish them for template specialization.

Comment: "if you write `std :: unique_ptr<int[]> p(new int[2]);`" - this is because the standard defines a partial specialization of `unique_ptr` for array types. So the constructor takes `int*` rather than `int (*)[]` as you'd otherwise expect, and there are some other differences (for example no `operator->`, but `operator[]` instead).

Comment: `typedef <typename T> using shared_array = shared_ptr<T[]>;`

Comment: @spraff: Nope, `shared_ptr` has no specialization for `T[]`.

Comment: @Xeo: so why's that then? Something to do with the fact that `unique_ptr` has the deleter type in the template parameters, whereas `shared_ptr` uses type erasure? I suppose you write `shared_ptr<int> p(new int[2], std::default_delete<int[]>());` or thereabouts, but then you don't get `operator[]`.

Comment: @Steve: I have no idea about the rationale, but I'd believe it's something like that.

Comment: Of course `shared_array` isn't needed because you can use `std::array` or `std::vector`, and these work just fine with smart pointers and `new` and `delete`. There's no need to use `new[]` or `delete[]` anymore.

Comment: -1: For talking about `std::shared_array` that doesn't exist.

Comment: @bames53: by exactly the same argument there's no need for the array specialization of `unique_ptr`, and yet somehow that slipped through into the standard. So I don't think it's a matter of course that `shared_array` didn't make it, whether it's needed or not.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes, the same argument applies to the array specialization of `unique_ptr`. I would say not including `shared_array` actually was the natural thing (as far as I know no one thought enough of it to bother to include it in any proposal). The fact that the array specialization of `unique_ptr` was included is the oddity.

Comment: std::array is not a reasonable replacement for shared_ptr<type[]> when you don't need the size parameter since it wastes memory.

Answer (score 6):

There is no "magical" way to detect whether a `int*` refers to:

- a single heap allocated integer
- a heap allocated array
- an integer *in* a heap allocated array

The information was lost by the type system and no runtime method (portable) can fix it. It's infuriating and a serious design flaw (*) in C that C++ inherited (for the sake of compatibility, some say).

However, there *are* some ways of dealing with arrays in smart pointers.

First, your `unique_ptr` type is incorrect to deal with an array, you should be using:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> p(new int[10]);
```

which is *meant* to call `delete[]`. I know there is talk of implementing a specific warning in Clang to catch obvious mismatches with `unique_ptr`: it's a quality of implementation issue (the Standard merely says it's UB), and not all cases can be covered without WPA.

Second, a `boost::shared_ptr` can have a custom deleter which *could* if you design it to call the correct `delete[]` operator. However, there is a `boost::shared_array` especially designed for this. Once again, detection of mismatches is a quality of implementation issue. `std::shared_ptr` suffers the same issue (*edited after ildjarn's remark*).

I agree that it's not pretty. It seems so obnoxious that a design flaw (*) from the origins of C haunts us today still.

(*) some will say that C leans heavily toward avoiding overhead and this would have added an overhead. I partly disagree: `malloc` always know the size of the block, after all.

Comment: I think that the reason in C is a bit more complex. If dynamically allocated arrays yielded different types (as auto allocated do size being part of the type) then you could not write a `strlen` function to manage all liberals, for example, and there are no overloads in C. The alternative would be having a single array type that contained the size as a member, but that would make mapping hardware with arrays hard (were would you store the size? maintain size and a pointer to the data? that would leave us in square one: a pointer refers to either one or more elements...)

Comment: BTW: I the list of options, don't forget that a pointer can also refer to auto or static memory, or shared memory, hardware addresses... Each of which has the two possibilities: array or single element (which can belong to an array) +1

Comment: My suggestion in the "background" section of the question would be a no-overhead solution, but not backwards-compatible.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I think this is a false issue. `delete[]` knows how many elements were built as it invokes the destructors. The typical way of dealing with this would be using tail padding: `struct Array { size_t size; char content[]; };` and return a pointer to the content. This means that if you *assume* it is an array, then you know the size. Of course it does not help with the pointer/array distinction, but in C there is no solution. In C++, a debug implementation could "remember" if the allocation was performed by `new` or `new[]` and check that the correct `delete` is invoked.

Comment: C, having no function overloading and no templates, doesn't really *need* strict type distinctions as much as C++ does.

Comment: @dan04: it's a point of view. Personally I think that with a proper array built-in in C, lots of memory overflows would have been avoided. Too many people forget to pass the size along the pointer to the buffer, or make mistakes when passing it; typical: `memcpy(buffer, sizeof(buffer), src)` when `buffer` is not an array but a pointer...

Comment: @MatthieuM. I agree that in C++ it is a non-issue, and also that having a proper array type in C would have helped removing many bugs, but in a systems language you need to be able to access raw areas in memory as if they were *array*s and do so without having to embed a *size* that might not fit the memory layout of the hardware. Now, that does not mean that there could not be an *array* type and a *buffer* (or *raw_array*) type. Then again, you might need to duplicate otherwise similar code to handle the two variants... I am not argueing, just bringing up potential design issues.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Yes, I understand the concern of mapping directly to raw memory. Still I think this is fairly easily address by defining a Range structure, that has either a size and pointer or just two pointers as in C++ half-open range. Then you are free to make your functions against that interface :)

Comment: @Matthieu You're making the mistake of assuming that the purpose of C is to be a high-level language that protects you from the consequences of poor programming. That is not true. C is there to make it less painful to write low-level code; some of the enormously nasty things you can do in C are there because they're _needed_ to make complex apps work at all. (This was especially true on smaller machines where the cost of overheads could mean the difference between something that would fit in memory and something that wouldn't.)

Comment: @DonalFellows: I am sorry... where did "overloads" popped up in the conversation ? While I really like them (though not to the extent that I support the awkward way they are introduced in C11), I don't think it came up here yet.

Comment: @Matthieu The real key is whether the other language (C in this case) will pass the result/argument correctly. If it's just an opaque token, it doesn't have to interpret it (and in fact, long experience tells me that it turns out to be better to put all interpretation behind an API). The problem only really comes when you're passing around something larger than a machine word, i.e. a struct or object, as that has certainly been a consistency problem in the past and it maximizes the potential for misunderstanding of object sizes (critical).

Comment: The long and short of it is that passing around an opaque-but-otherwise-ordinary pointer (which could be to anything) is easier than passing around an object by value. Yes, it has significant downsides in memory management; that's what you have to put up with.

Comment: "*`std::shared_ptr` provides the same syntax that `std::unique_ptr` does.*" If by this you mean that `std::shared_ptr<int[]> p(new int[10]);` will work, it doesn't.

Comment: @ildjarn: right, I thought it did, though with hindsight it could be non-trivial: what if someone grabs a reference within the array ? (current with pointers).

Answer (score 3):

From [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee410601.aspx):

> (A partial specialization `unique_ptr<Type[]>` manages array objects allocated with `new[]`, and has the default deleter `default_delete<Type[]>`, specialized to call `delete[] _Ptr`.)

I added the two final square brackets, seems like a typo as it doesn't make sense without them.

Comment: Reading Armen Tsirunyan's answer, I don't know what to make of this. I'll let it stand, as an interesting point. Perhaps I'm missing something fundamental.

Comment: I think MSDN means that if you write `shared_ptr<int[]> p(new int[2])` then `delete[]` will be used. But if you write `shared_ptr<int> p (new int[2])` this will result in UB.

Comment: I suppose you could write something like  `shared_ptr<int>i=shared_ptr<int>::allocate()` and `shared_ptr<int[]>i=shared_ptr<int[]>::allocate(n)` and prohibit construction from raw pointers. (For your own `shared_ptr`, I mean.)

Answer (score 3):

`std::unique_ptr` is not meant for array as I quote latest boost document:

> Normally, a `shared_ptr` cannot correctly hold a pointer to a
>   dynamically allocated array. See `shared_array` for that usage.

If you want to memory management for array of pointer, you have a few options depend on your requirement:

1. Use `boost::shared_array`
2. Use `std::vector` of `boost::shared_ptr`
3. Use boost pointer container like `boost::ptr_vector`

Comment: I suppose the mutual exclusion of member `operator[](size_t)` and `operator*()` would be a good clue.

Comment: You're backing up your claim about unique_ptr with a quote about shared_ptr. Weird.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` is specialized for array types and will use `delete[]` if you specify one (e.g., `std::unique_ptr<int[]>`).  `std::vector` is a better option though. I don't see any need for `shared_array`

Answer (score 0):

[Nicolai Josuttis](http://www.josuttis.com/) ⟶ Note that the default deleter provided by `std::shared_ptr` calls delete, not delete[]. This means that the default deleter is appropiate only if a shared pointer owns a single object created with new. Unfortunately, creating a `std::shared_ptr` for an array is possible but wrong:

```
std::shared_ptr<int>(new int[10]) //error but compiles
```

So if you use new[] to create an array of objects you have to define your own deleter. For example

```
std::shared_ptr<int> ptr(new int[10], 
                         [](int* p){ delete[] p; });
```

or

```
std::shared_ptr<int> ptr(new int[10], 
                         std::default_delete<int[]>());
```

For me this is the best solution!