# Why std::shared_ptr calls destructors from base and derived classes, where delete calls only destructor from base class?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

Why when using std::shared_ptr deallocation calls destructors from both base and derived classes when second example calls only destructor from base class?

```
class Base
{
public:
    ~Base()
    {
        std::cout << "Base destructor" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    ~Derived()
    {
        std::cout << "Derived destructor" << std::endl;
    }
};

void virtual_destructor()
{
    {
        std::cout << "--------------------" << std::endl;
        std::shared_ptr<Base> sharedA(new Derived);
    }

    std::cout << "--------------------" << std::endl;
    Base * a = new Derived;
    delete a;
}
```

Output:

```
--------------------
Derived destructor
Base destructor
--------------------
Base destructor
```

I was expecting the same behaviour in both cases.

Comment: your base destructor is not virtual to begin with. You are looking for trouble...

Comment: See [this "question"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899790/shared-ptr-magic).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`delete a` is undefined behaviour, because the class `Base` does not have a virtual destructor and the "complete object" of `*a` (more accurately: the most-derived object containing `*a`) is not of type `Base`.

The shared pointer is created with a deduced deleter that deletes a `Derived *`, and thus everything is fine.

(The effect of the deduced deleter is to say `delete static_cast<Derived*>(__the_pointer)`).

If you wanted to reproduce the undefined behaviour with the shared pointer, you'd have to convert the pointer immediately:

```
// THIS IS AN ERROR
std::shared_ptr<Base> shared(static_cast<Base*>(new Derived));
```

In some sense, it is The Right Way for the shared pointer to behave: Since you are *already* paying the price of the virtual lookup for the type-erased deleter and allocator, it is only fair that you don't then *also* have to pay for another virtual lookup of the destructor. The type-erased deleter remembers the complete type and thus incurs no further overhead.

Comment: *it is only fair that you don't then also have to pay for another virtual lookup of the destructor* The implementation of `shared_ptr` **will** pay the cost of the dynamic dispatch if the destructor is virtual. Cost is *not* the reason why this is done there are other features of shared pointers that would not work if the deleter did not encode the type of the original pointer (which might or not be the type of the complete object), like for example aliasing subobjects, or maintaining shared pointers with different types (base vs. derived). The last paragraph is filled with issues.

Comment: BTW, disabling the virtual dispatch inside the deleter would cause undefined behavior in cases like: `struct base { virtual ~base(); }; struct derived : base {}; base *p = new derived; std::shared_ptr<base> sp(p);` and this is probably a common use case (a pointer to an interface is handed into a library that manages it internally via a shared pointer)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Maybe I didn't quite make clear that the deleter doesn't *disable* virtual dispatch (which is not possible anyway, for delete expressions), but it gives you the option of not requiring virtual destructors if you only use your hierarchy in shared pointers.

Comment: but the call to the deleter delete function is virtual. because it cannot be stored as its concrete type into the shared pointer which is type erased. therefore, we pay virtual call at destruction for any type. and double virtual indirection for type with virtual destructors. one for the deleter operator () (or destruct() function in Matthieu's code) and one further next inside the `delete` operator.

Comment: @v.oddou: Yes, indeed, `shared_ptr` itself always pays the price of type erasure.

Answer (score 7):

A missing piece to Kerrek SB's answer is *how does the `shared_ptr` knows the type* ?

The answer is that there are 3 types involved:

- the static type of the pointer (`shared_ptr<Base>`)
- the static type passed to the constructor
- the actual dynamic type of the data

And `shared_ptr` **does not know of the actual dynamic type**, but knows which static type was passed to its constructor. It then practices type-erasure... but *remembers* somehow the type. An example implementation would be (without sharing):

```
template <typename T>
class simple_ptr_internal_interface {
public:
    virtual T* get() = 0;
    virtual void destruct() = 0;
}; // class simple_ptr_internal_interface

template <typename T, typename D>
class simple_ptr_internal: public simple_ptr_internal_interface {
public:
    simple_ptr_internal(T* p, D d): pointer(p), deleter(std::move(d)) {}

    virtual T* get() override { return pointer; }
    virtual void destruct() override { deleter(pointer); }

private:
    T* pointer;
    D deleter;
}; // class simple_ptr_internal

template <typename T>
class simple_ptr {
    template <typename U>
    struct DefaultDeleter {
        void operator()(T* t) { delete static_cast<U*>(t); }
    };

    template <typename Derived>
    using DefaultInternal = simple_ptr_internal<T, DefaultDeleter<Derived>>;

public:
    template <typename Derived>
    simple_ptr(Derived* d): internal(new DefaultInternal<Derived>{d}) {}

    ~simple_ptr() { this->destruct(); }

private:
    void destruct() { internal->destruct(); }

    simple_ptr_internal_interface* internal;
}; // class simple_ptr
```

Note that thanks to this mechanism, `shared_ptr<void>` is actually meaningful and can be used to carry *any* data an properly dispose of it.

Note also that there is a penalty involved with this semantics: the need for *indirection* required for the type-erasure of the `deleter` attribute.