# Any way around using a base class that does not have a virtual destructor?

Tags: c++

This specific case is for Arduino, but the question applies in general.  The SDK provides a `Client` class, from which other classes (`WiFiClient`, `EthernetClient`, and others) derive.

In my own class I have a field of type `Client*` which can hold any of those derived classes. I'd like to be able to `delete clientfield` in my class (specifically in its destructor), but because `Client` does not provide a virtual destructor, that would cause undefined behaviour.

Any suggestions for ways to work around this?

I could Modify `Client` to add the destructor, but that's not ideal since anyone using my code would have to make that same change on their system.

Comment: Where and how is `clientfield` declared and initialized?

Comment: Do you know the concrete class at the time `clientfield` is originally assigned? You could do what `std::shared_ptr` does, and capture a deleter at that time. In fact, I guess you could just use `std::shared_ptr` for `clientfield`, and have it do its magic.

Comment: *Any suggestions for ways to work around this?* -- Use [std::shared_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49228156/why-does-unique-ptr-only-call-the-base-destructor-when-shared-ptr-calls-the-der)

Comment: Are there any virtual member functions in `Client`? If there aren't, then what good does a `Client*` pointer do you? If there are, then it's kind of odd for the library authors not to give it a virtual destructor.

Comment: @OP Maybe `Client` is not meant to be derived from?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie as stated in the question, the SDK itself already derives WiFiClient and EthernetClient from it, so I don't believe that's the case.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yes there are a number of virtual member functions in ```Client```.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik @PaulMcKenzie  I was under the impression ```std::shared_ptr``` should be avoided on Arduino.  A quick test shows it might actually work though, so I'll convert everything to that and see if it causes any issues.

Comment: @Jochen If the virtual destructor is missing, and there are virtual functions in the base class, go to the authors of the library and submit a bug report.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is cast the pointer to its actual derived type before deleting it, for example:

```
if (isWifiClient)
    delete static_cast<WifiClient*>(clientfield);
else if (isEthernetClient)
    delete static_cast<EthernetClient*>(clientfield);
```

Comment: You can use `dynamic_cast` for the `is...` checks, eg: `if (WifiClient *wifi = dynamic_cast<WifiClient*>(clientfield)) delete wifi; else if (EthernetClient *eth = dynamic_cast<EthernetClient*>(clientfield)) delete eth;`

Comment: Unfortunately dynamic_cast cannot be used on Arduino, since rtti is disabled on the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

If base class doesn't have virtual destructor, you have to delete it from pointer of it derived type.

Casting is one option:

```
// No need of `if` as deleting null pointers is noop.
delete dynamic_cast<WifiClient*>(client);
delete dynamic_cast<EthernetClient*>(client);
```

Better alternative is to use `std::shared_ptr` which handles the (type-erased) destructor.

```
std::shared_ptr<Client> client = std::make_shared<WifiClient>(/*..*/);
```

Note, "refactoring" to `std::unique_ptr<Client>` (as ownership is not *shared* for example) would lead to your original issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `shared_ptr`? It implements the dynamic dispatch in its deleter. It is important, though, that you allocate the correct `shared_ptr` type:

```
shared_ptr<Client> clientfield = make_shared<WifiClient>();
```

or

```
shared_ptr<Client> clientfield = shared_ptr<WifiClient>(new <WifiClient>());
```

This would be wrong:

```
shared_ptr<Client> clientfield(new <WifiClient>());
```

To make it correct again, you can pass a suitable deleter:

```
shared_ptr<Client> clientfield(new <WifiClient>(), default_delete<WifiClient>());
```