# Why there seem to be no need for virtual destructor when using smart pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, virtual-destructor

Consider the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Base
{
    ~Base() {std::cout << "~Base()" << std::endl;}
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    ~Derived() {std::cout << "~Derived()" << std::endl;}
};

int main()
{
    // why does the right destructor is called at program exit?
    std::shared_ptr<Base> sptrBase{std::make_shared<Derived>()}; 
}
```

which outputs

> ~Derived()
>
> ~Base()

My `Base` class doesn't have a virtual destructor. However, when using a `Derived` object via a smart pointer to `Base`, the correct `~Derived()` destructor seems to be correctly invoked at program exit. Why does this happen (instead of undefined behaviour)? Is it because the `Derived` type is somehow "recorded" when the result of `std::make_shared<Derived>()` is converted into `std::shared_ptr<Base>`? Or is it plain UB?

Comment: What do you mean "instead of undefined behaviour"? By definition undefined behavior can be anything, including what you see.

Comment: @Adam I should actually ask if this is UB or not.

Comment: roughly speaking, `shared_ptr` contains a function pointer to the destructor, which is set correctly by `make_shared`

Comment: @MattMcNabb so the default deleter takes care of correct deletion?

Comment: Yes, because `make_shared<Derived>` creates a default deleter for Derived, not Base

Comment: @MattMcNabb ok, it was simpler than I though... I forgot that there is one more object involved, which is the deleter. Thanks! You should post an answer and I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: My question is indeed a dupe (saw this now), but probably of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3899790/3093378. I nominated the question for reopening so it can be closed under this dupe. Or, if someone can change the dupe, please do, as I think it's a better fit.

Comment: I am curious, I copy / pasted this code and received errors. I am on a Mac and tried updating GCC to version 4.9.2 (to attempt compiling) but it still does not compile. The number of errors I get is too large for a comment, but this is the first one: `foo.cpp: In function 'int main()':
foo.cpp:17:5: error: 'shared_ptr' is not a member of 'std'
     std::shared_ptr<Base> sptrBase{std::make_shared<Derived>()}; 
     ^`

Comment: @asimes compile with `-std=c++11`