# Segmentation fault from example in C++ reference for shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11

I took the example code from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr and compiled it locally, compiled it like this:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -D_GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP my_file.cpp
```

When I run it, I got the following output:

```
  Base::Base()
  Derived::Derived()
Created a shared Derived (as a pointer to Base)
  p.get() = 0x608029, p.use_count() = 1
Segmentation fault
```

Any idea why it has a seg fault?

I'm fairly new to C++, how would you usually debug this?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you compile with `-std=c++0x`? `std::shared_ptr` wasn't available until C++11, so you'd need `-std=c++11`

Comment: @CoryKramer C++0x was the working name of the standard, when it was believed that the process would be finished in '09 at the latest. The options are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the source code from the linked page verbatim, suggested changes to the command line:

1. Use `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14`.
2. Enable use of `pthread` library and make the compiler thread-aware.

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++11  -pthread my_file.cpp
g++ -Wall -std=c++14  -pthread my_file.cpp
```

Comment: It's not just for the library, it also makes gcc thread-aware (so that shared ptr's refcount becomes thread-safe, among other things )

Comment: @Cubbi not sure I understand your comment. Are you saying that if using standard C++ threads you should use `-pthread`? I thought `-std=c++11` should be enough.

Comment: @vsoftco unless gcc changed the defaults in 5.1, it needs -pthread (not to be confused with -lpthread)

Comment: @Cubbi can you briefly tell me why? Is it related to the `shared_ptr` only? I'm using threads (via OpenMP) in one of my applications and I want to make sure I'm not doing something stupid.

Comment: @vsoftco -fopenmp implies -pthread, according to man gcc. It passes -D_REENTRANT, at least  (actually i may be wrong on shared ptr safety, that depends on _GTHREAD

Comment: @Cubbi Thanks, but it is still unclear for me. Looking at `man g++`: *pthread Adds support for multithreading with the pthreads library.  This option sets flags for both the preprocessor and linker.* Say I just use `std::thread` in my program, and compile with `-std=c++11`. Should I use the `-pthread` flag? I thought that the `-std=c++11` will take care of that, as the new standard has implicit support for multi-threading, and the latter are not forced to be implemented via `pthread` (although most of the time they are).

Comment: @vsoftco GCC is designed to not generate thread-aware code unless requested. It requires `-pthread` for pthread-based implementations; other platforms will require some other option (like `-mthread` for Windows threads, `-threads` for HP-UX dce threads.) Hopefully, some time in the future, `-std=c++11`/`std=c++14`/etc will automatically imply `-pthread`/`-mthread`/etc.

Answer (score 0):

The example suffers from the 'base class not having virtual destructor on base class' problem. When destroying the Derived object with a pointer to Base the code simply calls the destructor of Base. Which is a Bad Thing (TM)

Comment: As mentioned on the cppreference page, there is no need for a virtual destructor, the smart pointer keeps track of which destructor to call. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3899790/3093378