# Creating unique_ptr<Base> when Base class has a protected destructor

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, destructor, unique-ptr

```
class Base {
public:
    Base() {}
    virtual void print()const = 0;
protected:
    virtual ~Base() { std::cout << "Base destructor\n\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    //std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> v1; 
    //The line above won't compile because: 'Base::~Base': cannot access protected member declared in class 'Base'
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> v2;
    return 0;
}
```

What is trying to call the destructor when I am creating the vector? Why it won't compile for the unique_ptr vector but would compile for the shared_ptr vector?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [shared\_ptr magic :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899790/shared-ptr-magic)

Comment: hey, when did the comment changed from *possibly duplicate* to *does this answer your question* :P

Comment: @appleapple Thank you. The question you referred to was helpful. The answers from Kerndog73 and Evg are more straight forward to solve the problem I had.

Comment: @appleapple https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337013/155739

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 thanks, well, I don't really like the new wording :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local variables `v1` and `v2` have automatic storage duration and will be automatically destructed when they go out of scope. The `std::vector` is irrelevant here: inside `vector::~vector()` the compiler will generate code for element destructors. Even if a vector is always empty (this is a run-time property!), this code still has to be generated. So let's simplify the code:

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> v1;
std::shared_ptr<Base> v2;
```

When `v1` goes out of scope, it has to be destroyed. The destructor generated by the compiler boils down to (*):

```
~unique_ptr() {
    delete ptr;
}
```

To generate code for `delete ptr`, the compiler needs the accessible destructor. It is protected, so the compilation fails.

Now let's look at `v2`. The compiler has to generate the destructor, too. But `shared_ptr` has a type-erased deleter for a managed object. This means that a managed object destructor will be called indirectly – through a virtual function:

```
struct shared_ptr_deleter_base {
    virtual void destroy() = 0;
    virtual ~shared_ptr_deleter_base() = default;
};

~shared_ptr() {
    // member shared_ptr::deleter has type shared_ptr_deleter_base*
    if (deleter)
        deleter->destroy();
}
```

To generate code for `deleter->destroy()`, you don't need to access `Base::~Base()` at all. The default constructor of `shared_ptr` simply sets `deleter` to a null pointer:

```
shared_ptr() {
    deleter = nullptr;
}
```

That's why `std::shared_ptr<Base> v2;` compiles: not only `Base::~Base()` is not called at the run-time, no call is ever generated by the compiler at the compile-time.

Let's consider this line:

```
std::shared_ptr<Base> v2(new Base());
```

Now the following constructor is called (note that it is a template with a separate parameter `U` that can be different from `T` in `shared_ptr<T>`):

```
template<class U>
shared_ptr(U* ptr) {
    deleter = new shared_ptr_deleter<U>(ptr);
}
```

Here `shared_ptr_deleter` is a concrete class derived from `shared_ptr_deleter_base`:

```
template<class T>
struct shared_ptr_deleter : shared_ptr_deleter_base {
    T* ptr;
    shared_ptr_deleter(T* p) : ptr(p) {}

    virtual void destroy() {
        delete ptr;
    }
};
```

To generate code for the constructor taking `new Base()`, the compiler has to generate code for `shared_ptr_deleter<Base>::destroy()`. Now it fails because the `Base::~Base()` is inaccessible.

(*) I present only simplified definitions just to demonstrate basic ideas without going into all the details that are not relevant to understanding the problem in question.

Answer (score 1):

`std::unique_ptr` can't access the destructor of `Base` because it's `protected`. `std::shared_ptr` uses a polymorphic deleter so `std::shared_ptr` only needs to access the destructor of `Base` when you create a new `std::shared_ptr`.

```
// this fails because the destructor of Base is inaccessible
std::unique_ptr<Base> a;

// this is ok because the destructor isn't required to instantiate the type
std::shared_ptr<Base> b;

// this fails because make_shared needs the destructor
std::shared_ptr<Base> c = std::make_shared<Base>();
```

"Polymorphic deleter" basically means that `std::shared_ptr` stores a pointer to a function that destroys the object. `std::unique_ptr` uses a "static deleter" that destroys the object directly. Here's some pseudo-code:

```
struct shared_ptr {
  ~shared_ptr() {
     deleter();
  }

  void (*deleter)(); // pointer to function that destroys the object
};

// shared_ptr doesn't try to call the destructor directly so we don't need access
// so this is ok
shared_ptr a;

shared_ptr make_shared() {
  // here we generate (with templates) a function that calls Base::~Base
  // then we set "deleter" to point to that function
  // the destructor has to be accessible for us to do this
}
// so we get an error here
shared_ptr b = make_shared();

struct unique_ptr {
  ~unique_ptr() {
    // unique_ptr calls the Base destructor directly
    // unique_ptr needs access to the destructor to instantiate the type
  }
};

// so we get an error here
unique_ptr c;
```

In your situation, `Base` happens to be abstract so you can use `std::shared_ptr<Base>` because you'll never need to write `std::make_shared<Base>()`. As long as subclasses of `Base` have `public` destructors, `std::make_shared` will be able to access them without giving you errors.

Comment: In `shared_ptr` constructor (or `make_shared()`) compiler not just "sets" the `deleter` function pointer, but also **generates** the code for the function (deleter) it points to. For `std::shared_ptr<Base> b;` no such code is generated, so the compilation succeeds.