# Is default d'tor enough for complex vectors?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

If my class has:

```
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Animal>> table;
```

While `Animal` is an abstract class that is inherited by others, will the default d'tor be enough?

I know that it will be enough for the vector itself but what about what is contained inside that vector?

Comment: To be clear, we are talking about the destriuctor for the class that contains `table`, and not the destructor for `Animal`, yes?

Comment: Don't overload questions by tacking on unrelated new questions please. `table` will be initialized with `size` default initialized `shared_ptr`s.

Comment: yes @user4581301

Comment: what do you mean by "will be initialized with size default initialized shared_ptrs" how may I know what's the default? I searched google and nothing found

Comment: @BigSur The default is the shared pointer equivalent of a nullptr https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr, as it says in the link 'constructs a shared_ptr with no managed object'.

Comment: I rolled back your question. There should be only one question asked per post, and you shouldn't change your question after you received an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a virtual destructor in `Animal` as a matter of good practise:

```
virtual ~Animal(){}
```

Though a virtual destructor [is not really needed to properly use polymorphism when using `shared_ptr`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3899790/6865932).

Credit to [@NathanOliver's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62584394/is-default-dtor-enough-for-complex-vectors/62584423?noredirect=1#comment110677774_62584423).

You don't need to worry about memory management in this instance.

Comment: I did that, but the default d'tor for my class (written above) is enough right?

Comment: Yes, it's enough, virtual pointer manage their own memory.

Comment: Thanks, may you answer my second question please ? (I'm accepting this as answer in 7 minutes duo to the limits here)

Comment: @BigSur one question per post please

Comment: I know but I can ask after 90 minutes and I need it to finish something

Comment: please any help? @bolov

Comment: @BigSur The rules are there for a reason, and they do not depend on how much in a hurry one is.

Comment: @BigSur, that's it, look to [john comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62584394/is-default-dtor-enough-for-complex-vectors/62584423?noredirect=1#comment110677284_62584394), study that, and later ask questions, that is in fact [how you should always do it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: While good pratice, a virtual destructor is not needed to properly use polymorphism with a `shared_ptr`.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899790/shared-ptr-magic

Comment: @NathanOliver, I wasn'r aware of it, nice to know, good share.

Comment: No problem.  It sure surprised me when I first discovered it.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I'll add it to the answer.