# no viable overloaded '=' for shared_ptr

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, methods, shared-ptr

What's wrong with my code:

```
class Game{
    private:
        mtm::Dimensions dimensions;
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Character>> board;
};


std::shared_ptr<Character> Game::makeCharacter(CharacterType type, Team team, units_t health,
units_t ammo, units_t range, units_t power) {
    std::shared_ptr<Character> out = nullptr;
    if (type ==SNIPER)
        out=mtm::Sniper(team,health,power,ammo,range);
    return out;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
no viable overloaded '='
        out=mtm::Sniper(team,health,power,ammo,range);
```

Note: `Sniper` inherits from the abstract class `Character`.

How may I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `new` when constructing the `Sniper` object, eg:

```
out = std::shared_ptr<mtm::Sniper>(new mtm::Sniper(team,health,power,ammo,range));
```

Or better, use `std::make_shared()` insted:

```
out = std::make_shared<mtm::Sniper>(team,health,power,ammo,range);
```

`out = mtm::Sniper(...)` does not work, because `std::shared_ptr<Character>` is expecting a `Character*` *pointer* to take ownership of (or another `std::shared_ptr<T>` to share ownership with, where `T` is convertible to `Character`).  You are constructing a local `Sniper` object and then trying to assign it to the `shared_ptr`, but a `Sniper` *object* is not implicitly convertible to a `Character*` pointer, but a `Sniper*` pointer is (since `Sniper` derives from `Character`).

And also, by default `std::shared_ptr` will `delete` the pointer it owns (unless you provide a different `deleter`), so you need to use `new` (or `std::make_shared()`) to ensure that object is constructed in dynamic memory that can be `delete`'d properly.  That means `new`'ing it.

Comment: @Josh Note the bit about `make_shared`. Prefer to use `make_shared` over plain old `new` because with `new` there is a window of vulnerability where the allocation can be leaked. If you use `make_shared`, you're protected end to end (or there's a really freaking nasty bug no one's reported yet)

Comment: @TedLyngmo, intersting read https://stackoverflow.com/q/3899790/6865932

Comment: @RemyLebeau may you reset the answer to the older version? I'm not allowed to user reset() or make_shared()

Comment: That's a new one. I'm getting used to "No `string`, `vector`, or smart pointers" in Stack Overflow questions, but not  "Use smart pointers, but use them wrong." I'd check that requirement with the professor or a TA, because that's just weird.

Comment: @user4581301 May you include some explanation of using these two in your solution, I didn't learn them and don't know what are you doing here, Plus why what I did is wrong?

Comment: @Josh: "*may you reset the answer to the older version?*" - no, but I have provided another alternative if you can't use `make_shared()` (why?).

Comment: @Josh wrong may be too strong a word for me to have used, less safe would have been a better choice. Say you `new` the `Sniper`, but before you can place it into the `shared_ptr`, where it becomes managed and safe, something goes wrong. There is now an opportunity for the `Sniper` to get lost and never be freed. `make_shared` closes this window. Sometimes not learning something in the lectures doesn't imply "Do not use" and instead means "Let's see which students read the documentation and usage notes and learned on their own." This is why I recommended checking.