# How to call derived destructor using my custom shared pointer class without virtual destructor?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I am creating my custom shared pointer class and I want my shared pointer class should call derived class destructor when it goes out of scope for the below code.

```
...
...
template<class T>
MySharedPtr<T>::MySharedPtr(T * p) : ptr(p), refCnt(new RefCount())
{
    refCnt->AddRef();
}

template<class T>
void MySharedPtr<T>::release()
{
    if (refCnt->Release() == 0) 
    {
        delete ptr;
        delete refCnt;
    }
    ptr = nullptr;
    refCnt = nullptr;
}
...
...
```

Base class destructor called when it goes out of scope but if I use `std::shared_ptr<Base> bptr(new Derived());`, it calls derived destructor and base destructor when it goes out of scope. How can I achieve the same behaviour with my custom class?

```
  class Base
    {
    public:
        
        Base() {
            cout << "Base default constructor" << endl;
        }
        ~Base() {
            cout << "Base destructor" << endl;
        }
        virtual void display() {
            cout << "in Base" << endl;
        }
    };
    
    class Derived : public Base
    {
    public:
        Derived() {
            cout << "Derived default constructor" << endl;
        }
        ~Derived() {
            cout << "Derived destructor" << endl;
        }
        virtual void display() {
            cout << "in Derived" << endl;
        }
    };
    int main()
    {
        MySharedPtr<Base> bptr(new Derived());
        bptr->display();
    }
```

Comment: Why isn't the destructor virtual ?

Comment: Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899790/shared-ptr-magic

Comment: @Frank I think it works well (i.e. calls derived dtor) even if you use `std::shared_ptr<Base> bptr(new Derived());` which is of type `std::shared_ptr<Base>`. I think it's part of the shared_ptr magic @Eljay pointed above.

Comment: A class with virtual functions should always have a virtual destructor for exactly that reason. But if you don't then you need a custom deleter that `dynamic_casts``the `Base*` to `Derived*` and deletes that. You end up just implementing a virtual destructor by hand.

Comment: *"How can I achieve the same behaviour with my custom class?"* -- given the "magic", it might be informative to take this the other way. How can one achieve your flawed behavior with `std::shared_ptr`? One way is to replace `MySharedPtr<Base> bptr(new Derived());` with two lines: `Base * raw_ptr = new Derived();` and `shared_ptr<Base> bptr(raw_ptr);`. ***Note:** for demonstration only; I am not recommending this as a general practice.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store a *callback* as part of the `RefCount` object which will be called when the reference count goes to zero. This callback can "remember" what it needs to do based on the pointer type that was used to originally construct the `MySharedPtr` object, even though the knowledge of that most derived type might have been lost elsewhere.

You must modify the constructor of `MySharedPtr` so that the type information is not immediately destroyed when the constructor is called. It needs to take `U*`, not `T*`. If it takes `T*`, then as soon as the constructor is entered, you already don't know what the original argument type was, since it has been converted to `T*`.

```
template <class T>
class MySharedPtr {
  public:
    template <class U>
    MySharedPtr(U* p);
  // ...
};

template <class T>
template <class U>
MySharedPtr<T>::MySharedPtr(U* p) : ptr(p), refCnt(new RefCount(p))
{
    refCnt->AddRef();
}
```

The `RefCount` constructor needs to set up the stored callback based on this pointer:

```
class RefCount {
  public:
    template <class U>
    RefCount(U* p) : deleter_{[p]{ delete p; }} {}
    // ...
    void invoke_deleter() { deleter_(); }

  private:
    int ref_count_ = 0;
    std::function<void()> deleter_;
};
```

So now, if you do:

```
MySharedPtr<Base> bptr(new Derived());
```

the `Derived*` will be passed to the `RefCount` constructor, and it will store a callback that calls `delete` on *that* pointer (of type `Derived*`) and not the `ptr` stored in the `MySharedPtr`, which is of type `Base*`.

You need to add the code to invoke this deleter when the ref count goes to 0:

```
template<class T>
void MySharedPtr<T>::release()
{
    if (refCnt->Release() == 0) 
    {
        refCnt->invoke_deleter();
        delete refCnt;
    }
    ptr = nullptr;
    refCnt = nullptr;
}
```

This is basically how `std::shared_ptr` works, although I suspect it doesn't use `std::function` internally, but some custom type erasure mechanism with lower overhead since it doesn't need to support most `std::function` features.

Comment: Hi Brian, I tried to implement it, based on your comment but my code is getting crashed in invoke_deleter() API.

Comment: @shrabanakumar I can't help you debug code that's crashing if I can't see the code. Try using a debugger.

Comment: Thanks Brian it worked for me , I forgot to pass argument to RefCount class. I wanted to achieve this for long time.

Comment: @shrabanakumar If this answer solved your problem, don't forget to click the checkmark to accept it.