# Inheriting from STL containers

Tags: c++, stl

Reading StackOverflow Q&A's such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034916/is-it-okay-to-inherit-implementation-from-stl-containers-rather-than-delegate) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898837/inherit-from-stl-container-in-c11), it would appear that inheriting from STL containers is generally a bad idea. I don't intend to do this in production code; however, I want to know if it will give me a valid quick and dirty test.

In our code, we make heavy use of the STL, and we wish to test how aligning memory to a 64-byte boundary will affect our code's performance. I was planning to test this by writing a simple custom allocator and having a simple class that inherits `std::vector` with the only change in the class being that the default allocator is my custom allocator and not `std::allocator` and then simply writing a script to use `sed` and replace all instances of `std::vector` with my new class. Using this approach, I will not ever have any pointers carrying through to the base class (*all* instances of `std::vector` have been replaced, so any pointers would be of my custom type instead), which appears to be the biggest concern with inheriting from STL. Is this a valid approach? Are there any other easier/safer alternatives? This is a 3 million line code base, so manually changing all instances of `std::vector` to use the custom allocator would be a very, very, time-consuming task to say the least.

Comment: Actually, there is no problem if you want to inherit from STL vector **privately**.

Comment: @SergeyA: Yes, but that wouldn't work for my situation as I need the STL's interface as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have C++11 support, rather than inheritance you could do a templated using statement:

```
template <class T>
using custom_vector = std::vector<T, custom_allocator<T>>;
```

Then use your script to sed `std::vector` to `custom_vector`.